# Upgrading Heron to 1.0.5 to use with OpenLayers 2.13.1?

Tags: installation, openlayers-2, heron-mapping-client

Can we use Openlayers 2.13.1 instead of openlayers 2.12 with heron 1.0.5 ?

If yes, then what changes we have to make and if no then what are the possibilities of its up gradation in future.

The major problem I have found with openlayers 2.12 is mouse wheel zoom.

It is not as smooth as in openlayers 2.13.1.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer is to add `tileManager: null` in the `Heron.options.map.settings`.

I found the answer here: https://github.com/heron-mc/heron-mc/issues/430, where the jpg showing the change in js file.